# How can I find voltage of capacitor in this question?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current

[image]

The question asks us to find the energy that is stored in capacitors C1 and C2. Firstly, I drawn the equivalent circuit and then determined currents.

[image]

i1=[3k/3k+(2k+4k)]*6 mA = 2 mA        ;     i2=6-i1= 4 mA

For finding W1, we should find V1. So, my lecturer made this operation:

V1= 4k * i1 = 8V

He equalized the voltage difference between terminals of 4k resistor with C1. But doesn't the voltage difference between the terminals of 4k resistor equal to 5k resistor and C1? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current flowing through the 5k resistor, so the voltage across it is zero.

> But doesn't the voltage difference between the terminals of 4k resistor equal to 5k resistor and C1?

This is essentially correct, but the 5k resistor has 0 volts across it, so in practice the voltage difference between the terminals of 4k resistor equal to C1.

$$V_{4k} = V_{5k} + V_C$$
$$V_{4k} = 0 + V_C$$
$$V_{4k} = V_C$$

The reason why there is no current through 5k resistor is, that the C1 acts like an open circuit for DC voltage. When nothing can flow through C1, nothing can flow through resistor that is in series with it.